# Accessing a link value from datatable event

Tags: function, datatable, hyperlink

I have a Bootstrap datatable with elements displaying data from a viewbag, as below.

```
<table id="table1" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Comment</td>
    </tr>

    @if(ViewBag.FinalOnLeave != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.FinalOnLeave)
        {

    <tr>
        <td>@item.Data</td>
        <td>@item.Content</td>
        <td><a class="comment" onclick="showDataId(@item.ID)" href="#">Comment</a></td>
    </tr>

        } 
    }
</table>
```

And the Datatable bootstrap code in Jquery is as below

```
   $("#table1").DataTable({
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bFilter": false
                    }});
```

// and the function that is supposed to get a selected id from the link is here below ..

```
function showDataId(dataID)
{
    // display alert

    alert(dataID);
}
```

but i did realize one thing, A-link does not function well in the datatable when i assign a function to capture a dataID value for each link, the function does not respond well.

So i tried a different method  using the datatable click event by identifying the class of the link , as below,

```
    $('#table1').on('click', 'a.comment', function (e) {

              //showDataId(dataID)

    });
```

My biggest challenge is, how do i access the @item.dataID from this datatable event

Answer (score 0):

I did actually find the solution as i was trying out, and it was pretty simple,

```
$('#table1').on('click', 'a.comment', function (e) {

           var dataid = this.id; // this is all i needed

           showDataId(dataid );

  });
```